# Add custom popup using Modal

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery, popup

Want to open a popup by clicking the button in homepage.
inside the popup form will be submitted using **Ajax call**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In layout file (change the layout as per your wish) **cms_index_index.xml** in *Sathya/Popup/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="custom.popup.widget" template="Sathya_Popup::popup.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And template file in ***Sathya/Popup/view/frontend/templates/popup.phtml***

```
<h1>
    <div class="subscribe-button-wrapper">
        <a class="action-print" href="#" id="click-me">Custom popup</a>
    </div>
</h1>
<div class="popup-modal">

<!--     if not using Ajax then please give the action controller URL here.-->

    <form action="#" class="popup-form-data-submit">
        <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name1">
        </label>
        <label>
            Content Invoice:
            <textarea name="content"></textarea>
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
     {
        "*": {
            "Sathya_Popup/js/popup": { }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Javascript file in **Sathya/Popup/view/frontend/web/js/popup.js**

```js
define(['jquery', 'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'], function ($, modal) {
    'use strict';
    $.widget('sathya.customWidgetPopupForm',{
        options:{
            PopupForms: '.popup-form-data-submit',
            popupLink : '.action-print'
        },
        _create: function () {
            console.log('popup-form-connected');
            this._super();
            let self = this;
            let popupOptions = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                modalClass: 'custom_popup_box'
            };
            modal(popupOptions, this.options.PopupForms);
            $(self.options.popupLink).on('click',function () {
                $(self.options.PopupForms).modal('openModal');
            });
            $(self.options.PopupForms).on('submit',function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                alert('submited');
                // use ajax function to save the data
                // console.log($('.subscribe-form-data').serializeArray());
            })
        }
    });
    return $.sathya.customWidgetPopupForm;

});
```

[image]
[image]